# Richtungspräpositionen von/aus, durch über

Tags: word-choice

If I want to translate in German:

> I moved from Berlin to Munich.

Will it be:
*Ich habe **aus*** oder ***von*** Berlin nach München umgezogen?

Ist it the same for the sentence:

> The train goes from Berlin to Munich.

Der Zug fährt aus/von Berlin nach München.

When is it *von* and when *aus*? I thought normally *aus* is used with cities. For example:

> Ich bin aus Berlin hergekommen.

Aber: *Ich bin von Berlin nach München hergekommen?*

What is the difference between sentences and (or) which one of them is right?

- Der Zug fährt über Berlin.
- Der Zug fährt durch Berlin.

Answer (score 1):

> Ich <s>habe</s>bin aus Berlin nach München umgezogen.
>
> Ich <s>habe</s>bin von Berlin nach München umgezogen.

This is tricky, because it depends on the other preposition. With *nach*, both are possible, it's a matter of personal preference. (*umgezogen haben* means *to have redressed*)

> Ich bin aus Berlin weggezogen.
>
> Ich bin von Berlin weggezogen.

I strongly tend towards *aus* but many many speakers like *von* better.

> Ich bin von Berlin ins Umland gezogen.
>
> Ich bin von Berlin an die See gezogen.
>
> Ich bin von Berlin hinter die Oder gezogen.

These **require** the *von*.

---

> Der Zug fährt von Berlin nach München.

Strictly *von*, because Berlin and München are train stations here. It's not important the train left the Berlin area at some moment during the journey.

> Ich bin aus Berlin hergekommen.

Yes. *Von* is also possible, a matter of personal preference.

> Ich bin aus Berlin nach München <s>her</s>gekommen?
>
> Ich bin von Berlin nach München <s>her</s>gekommen?

*Her-* verbs don't mix well with *nach*. Again, both *aus* and *von* are possible.

---

> Der Zug fährt über Berlin.

The train stops at Berlin, but does not end there. (*über* denotes a station name, in this case an arbitrary one in Berlin, most likely the *Hauptbahnhof*.)

> Der Zug fährt durch Berlin.

The trains runs through Berlin. (it may stop there, but this isn't required.)

Answer (score -3):

Ich fahre ab Berlin nach München. (ist einfach)

Comment: Versuchen sie "welschenpreposition" zu vestehen. Anstatt habe umgezogen  ,ich bin.... Umgezogen ist richtig.